# Echo custom taxonomy values

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am using Advanced Custom Fields for the taxonomy *agent*. What I am trying to do is have Agents that have there info put into the taxonomy so that they have there image, bio, phone, cell and email then when we create a new property and set it to say agent Jane Doe. Then it would show her info on that listing such as her image, phone, email ext. But if I would choose a different agent it would show there info. 
Below is the code that I have come up with but this will always show agent_16 no mater who is selected.

How can I set it so that it will show the agent info that is selected?

```
<div class="listing-agent">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns">

<?php 

$image = get_field('agent_image_d', 'agent_16');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"     />

<?php endif; ?>

         </div>
                 <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns">


<?php   // Get terms for post
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'agent' );
// Loop over each item since it's an array
if ( $terms != null ){
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
// Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
print $term->name ;
// Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
unset($term);
} } ?>

                     <div class="agent-title"><?php the_field(   'agent_title_d', 'agent_16' ); ?></div>
                     <div class="office-phone">Office: (555) 555-55555</div>
                     <div class="agent-cell"><?php the_field( 'agent_cell_d', 'agent_16' ); ?></div>

                     <div class="agent-fax"><?php the_field( 'agent_fax_d', 'agent_16' ); ?></div>
                     <div class="agent-email"><?php the_field( 'agent_email_d', 'agent_16' ); ?></div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get the list of custom taxonomy by following code :

```
    <?php 
//list terms in a given taxonomy using wp_list_categories (also useful as a widget if using a PHP Code plugin)

$taxonomy     = 'genre';
$orderby      = 'name'; 
$show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title        = '';

$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      => $orderby,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title
);
?>

<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

Do check and let me know if you find it usefull